# Angular Communication Parent/Child in modals problem

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, vmware-clarity

I'm still learning how do components communicate between them, so I have my parentView, inside it had a modal with the components of [vmware-clarity](https://clarity.design/documentation/modals), but in my work, they told me to move it to a separate component.

parentView(Before)

```
<button class="btn btn-cris" (click)="confirm=true">Create Project</button>
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="confirm">
    ///modal Content
</clr-modal>
```

I change it to:
parentView:

```
<button class="btn btn-cris" (click)="confirm=true">Create Project</button>
<app-myModal [confirm]="confirm"></app-myModal>
```

modalView.html:

```
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="confirm">
    ///modal Content
</clr-modal>
```

modalView.ts:

```
export class QSubInitialProcessComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('confirm') confirm: boolean;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

But now when I close the modal with the default "x" button, I can't reopen it, when it was only one component you could close it and opened it.

I'm guessing it has something to do with parent and child communication, but I'm not quite sure. As far as I know, the "x" button that comes by default with the clarity component changes the value automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly on the right track here. I believe your issue lies here:

```
<app-myModal [confirm]="confirm"></app-myModal>
```

This is a *one-way binding* from your parent to your new modal view component. When your `clr-modal` changes this flag to `false` for your modal view, your parent likely still thinks it `true`.

What you need to do is introduce *two-way binding* to your intermediate modal view. You can do this with a simple addition to the modal view:

```
@Input('confirm') confirm: boolean;
@Output() confirmChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Then, associate your two-way binding with your parent automatically by using a *banana-in-a-box*:

`<app-myModal [(confirm)]="confirm"></app-myModal>`

The banana-in-a-box is just syntactic sugar for using your Input and Output at the same time.
For more info, see the official guide:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#basics-of-two-way-binding

If the above is not enough to solve the problem, it could also be that you're two-way-bound with `confirm` from the `clr-modal`'s output. You can try unboxing the association like this:

```
<clr-modal [clrModalOpen]="confirm" (clrModalOpenChange)="confirmChange.emit($event)">
    ///modal Content
</clr-modal>
```

I would expect then that your modal view component would then truly act as a passthrough for the actual modal's open state.

Comment: I change it just like you said, added the `@Output() confirmChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();` and to the parent view `<app-myModal [(confirm)]="confirm"></app-myModal>` but it is still not working, am i missing something?

Comment: could it be because of the `<clr-modal>` component? I don't where it changes the value of confirm, I just know it does it

Comment: @RicardoSanchezSantos I've updated my answer. Remember that banana-in-a-box is two-way binding, so `clr-modal` is changing `confirm` due to usage of that.

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to confirm that your team wants you to move the modal to its own component in this way, since I think it would be more appropriate to move the modal *content* to a new component, resulting in `<clr-modal...><app-myModal></app-myModal></clr-modal>`

Comment: to be honest, that was my first approach, and the modal worked, I could open and closed as many times i want, but the content wasn't displaying

Comment: I'm not experienced with the modal utility you're using here so I can't comment on that, unfortunately.